# Split a column by 1000 value for each group in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, split

I have a column with N row like this

| Column A |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| .. |
| .. |
| .. |
| 999,999 |
| 1,000,000 |

I want outcome like this:
('1','2','3',...,'1000')
('1001','1002',...,'2000')
...

each list contains 1000 value and separate exactly like that.

Comment: i mean a pandas dataframe with 1 column and multiple row

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Python list named my_list you can use:

```
chunk = 1000
new_list = [my_list[i:i+chunk] for i in range(0, len(my_list), chunk)]
```

I am not clear about the format of your items, but assuming they are numbers and you want to convert to a list of strings as you seem to indicate then you could use something like the code below and then export to CSV.

```
result = []  
 
for item in new_list:
    x = [str(y) for y in item]
    result.append(x)
```

Comment: I got the idea, but how can i export them to csv or excel file with 1 list in 1 cell, example like i have a colimn with 6877 row, make it 7 list, i need them in 7 cell in csv or excel , tks

Comment: @Annn Please don't move the target: How to export something is _not at all_ part of your stated question. Think long and hard about what you want to ask, then ask it well, and stick to it (apart from minor adjustments). Anything beyond that should be a new question.

Comment: I've modified my answer to convert the format, but in-line with @Titmus exporting is another coding question.

Answer (score -1):

If you are parsing a CSV, I would suggest you using the `pandas` lib like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df_groups = pd.read_csv('data.csv', chunksize=1000)

for group in df_groups:
    print(group)
```

This will print each group of 1000 rows to the console. You can then process each group of data as needed.

Comment: OP didn't say they were parsing a CSV, they say they have a list...

Comment: @snakecharmerb Which doesn't mean they've just read these million integers from a CSV file though :)